# jQuery linking malfunction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add my tic-tac-toe game to my home page but for some reason the jQuery isn't doing anything. What's wrong with this? I'm assuming that all of this is an error with my linking in my html but I'm not sure. Sorry for the lengthy code, I figured I might as well post everything just in case the issue wasn't where I thought it was.
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css' />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
             <h3>The Internet</h3>

        </div>
        <ul><a href="http://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>

        </ul>
        <ul><a href="http://www.4chan.org/g/">/g/</a>

        </ul>
        <ul><a href="http://www.4chan.org/wg/">/wg/</a>

        </ul>
        <ul><a href="http://www.google.com/voice/">Google Voice</a>

        </ul>
        <ul><a href="http://www.codecademy.com/tracks">Codecademy</a>

        </ul>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <button type='button'>New Game</button>
                <td id='c1'></td>
                <td id='c2'></td>
                <td id='c3'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id='c4'></td>
                <td id='c5'></td>
                <td id='c6'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id='c7'></td>
                <td id='c8'></td>
                <td id='c9'></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    background-color: white;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 75px;
    font-family: cursive;
    color: #333333;
    text-align: center;
}
a {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: cursive;
}
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
table, td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: Cursive;
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-left: 105px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #969696;
    color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    table-layout: fixed;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}
button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: -1124px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Cursive;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #1d3da5;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: #3F5DC2;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Creates the variables needed to be manipulated later
    var X = 'X';
    var O = 'O';
    var currentPlayer;
    var turnCount = 0;
    var xMoves = [];
    var oMoves = [];
    var cellTracker;
    var winAlert;
    var winConditions = [
        ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'],
        ['c4', 'c5', 'c6'],
        ['c7', 'c8', 'c9'],
        ['c1', 'c4', 'c7'],
        ['c2', 'c5', 'c8'],
        ['c3', 'c6', 'c9'],
        ['c1', 'c5', 'c9'],
        ['c3', 'c5', 'c7']
    ];
    var button = $('button');

    /*Set's the current player to X if turnCount is odd
And to O if turnCount is even*/
    var setCurrentPlayer = function () {
        if (turnCount % 2 === 0) {
            currentPlayer = O;
        } else {
            currentPlayer = X;
        }
    };

    //Pushes cellTracker's value to the curent player's move variable
    var storeMoves = function () {
        if (currentPlayer === X) {
            xMoves.push(cellTracker);
        } else if (currentPlayer === O) {
            oMoves.push(cellTracker);
        }
    };

    //Compares players moves with the winConditions to determine a winner
    var determineWin = function (pMoves) {
        for (var i = 0; i < winConditions.length; i++) {
            if (winConditions[i].length > pMoves.length) {
                continue;
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < winConditions[i].length; j++) {
                winAlert = false;
                for (var k = 0; k < pMoves.length; k++) {
                    if (pMoves[k] === winConditions[i][j]) {
                        winAlert = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!winAlert) break;
            }
            if (winAlert) {
                alert(currentPlayer + " wins!");
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    //Determines if the game is over
    var determineEnd = function () {
        if (turnCount === 9 && winAlert === false) {
            alert("Tie game!");
        }
        if (winAlert === true) {
            $('td').off('click.mygame', clickHandler);
        }
    };

    //Calls the above functions to simulate the game
    var clickHandler = function () {
        turnCount += 1;
        setCurrentPlayer();
        $(this).text(currentPlayer);
        cellTracker = $(this).attr('id');
        storeMoves();
        determineWin(currentPlayer == 'X' ? xMoves : oMoves);
        determineEnd();
        console.log(turnCount, xMoves, oMoves, winAlert);
    };

    //Calls the clickHandler function when a cell is clicked
    $('td').one('click.mygame', clickHandler);

    //Starts a new game when the New Game button is clicked
    $('button').bind('click', function () {
        $('td').empty();
        turnCount = 0;
        xMoves = [];
        oMoves = [];
        winAlert = false;
        $('td').off('click');
        $('td').one('click.mygame', clickHandler);
    });
});
```

EDIT This is what the console logs when the page is loaded.

```
[13:00:52.689] Unknown property 'user-select'.  Declaration dropped. @ file:///C:/Users/Tim/Documents/stylesheet.css:42
[13:00:52.690] ReferenceError: $ is not defined @ file:///C:/Users/Tim/Documents/script.js:1
[13:00:52.694] The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @ file:///C:/Users/Tim/Documents/home_page.html
```

Comment: any console output? Exceptions?

Comment: In your header, your script `src` should be `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.X/jquery-ui.min.js` instead of `//...`

Comment: @AndrewPeacock - if it's running on a webserver, there's no need for the protocol.

Comment: Is anything showing up in your console? also, you don't appear to be using jQuery UI

Comment: Why are you including jQuery UI twice?

Comment: @j08691 - to make sure it's really loaded? Of course, including the regular jQuery script would be a good idea as well.

Comment: @adeneo - jQuery UI: so nice, he loaded it twice.

Comment: @dstronczak Yeah but I don't know what they mean, I'll post them in an edit.
And to all of you who are pointing out my mistake of calling ui twice, I have now fixed that and it still isn't responding.

Comment: Even after editing the question, you need to include your `script` file after the `jquery ui` . Change that order as well

Comment: Do as @Sushanth says and this problem ReferenceError: $ is not defined @ file:///C:/Users/Tim/Documents/script.js:1 will go away, and it will likely work....I suggested it it in my post as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I don't see you including the `jquery` file in the first place.**

you are including `jquery ui` twice

And change this

```
 <script src="//ajax.
```

to

```
 <script src="http://ajax.
```

*When working on local*

This the order in which you are supposed to load the files are

```
        // First jQuery
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        // Second jQuery UI
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
       // Then comes your script
      <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Comment: This is the exact same order I have in my answer....how did mine not work, and yours did.....something fishy

Comment: @Kylek I fixed the ui to call the base jquery script. The issue was with the lack http calling.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include Jquery...

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You probably just included the ui, twice, instead replace that first line, with the line I have above

So your header code would be...

```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Comment: @user2449973.. include your script file after `jQuery ui`

Comment: Did you put your script.js file last?? as @Sushanth suggested ?  Thats most likely the reason....if its not that, then it might be a syntax error somewhere in your javascript.

Comment: Thank you, both of you but that did not solve the problem either. The script.js file was loaded after jquery but before jquery-ui. I edited my html to load it last but it did nothing.

Comment: well then unfortunately its a syntax error, somewhere....was that tic-tac toe code ever working?? Did you write it, or get it from somewhere??

Comment: I wrote it myself and it was working when tested yesterday.
The issue was solved by Sushath's response. Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: I really dont understand how that response solved your issue, its including ui twice, again......and my answer above is the exact same order as well....please explain